# Find all monotonic functions $f : \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ that satisfy $f''(x) + xf'(x) - (\delta+\gamma f(x))(f'(x))^2>0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, convex-analysis, nonlinear-analysis

I would like to find a set of functions that satisfy the following:

> Find all monotonic functions $f : \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ that satisfy $f''(x) + xf'(x) - (\delta+\gamma f(x))(f'(x))^2>0$

where $\gamma$ and $\delta$ are finite, non-zero constants. (A previous version of the question had $\gamma = \delta \equiv 1$, but this need not necessarily be the case).

The equation in the inequality is the derivative of a generalised log-odds function, the condition implying the final logistic curve is strictly increasing. Ideally, bounding the inequality by taking limits as $x\to\pm\infty$ should lead to an expression dependent solely on the parameters $\gamma$ and $\delta$ ${}^{1}$.

Properties that would naturally seem to be needed are $f'(x)\to 0$ and $f''(x)\to 0$ as $x \pm\infty$. Two good candidates I have found that would satisfy this are:

1. $f(x) = \text{arcsinh}(x)$, and
2. $f(x) = \tanh{(x)}$,

yet I'm not sure how to exploit their limiting behaviour to reduce the inequality to a simple form for $\gamma$ and $\delta$ (i.e., no explicit dependence on $x$). How can I do this in a rigorous manner? Are there any other suitable monotonic functions $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$?

---

${}^{1}$ This is for optimisation purposes guaranteeing the monotonicity of the logistic curve for some functional form of $f(x)$. In reality $x$ will never reach $\pm\infty$; it will exist in the interval $\left(\Phi^{-1}(\varepsilon),\Phi^{-1}(1-\varepsilon)\right)$ where $\mathcal{O}(\varepsilon) \sim 10^{-6}$. Therefore, for practical purposes, if bounding the inequality via the *asymptotic* limiting behaviour of $f(x)$ is too troublesome, we can also bound it by assessing its value as $x\to \pm 5$.

Comment: What makes this functional inequality  interesting? Looks rather arbitrary at a glance

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen it is a derived quantity from a problem I am investigating in my PhD research. Without going into too much detail, I am modelling the distribution in two classes for the purposes of a logistic regression. Class 1 is standard normal and class 2 is a transformed normal distribution, which takes a general form related to [Johnson's $S_U$ distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_SU-distribution). The final logistic curve *must* be strictly increasing - the functional inequality in the question is the derivative of the log-odds function for some general form of $f$.

Comment: You might also want to specify constraints.  For example, what type of boundedness at infinity are you interested in?  What should initial conditions be?

Comment: @Doug this is indeed a good point; in my problem, as I'm interested in optimising the logistic curve for some parameters, bounding this functional inequality ultimately bounds the parameters themselves, which is necessary and sufficient for optimisation. So, as $x\to\pm\infty$, the above functional inequality should be bounded.

Comment: Have you tried a power series approach?

Comment: @Doug I've thought about it, but have not explicitly tried it yet. The series will need to be bounded above and must take a form such that $(1 + \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n)^2$ grows slower than $x^2, \ \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ (see the answer from Thomas Andrews below for why this is the case). Challenging to say the least. Any ideas?

Comment: No, I don't have any other ideas..

Comment: @neurofunk_quant Given how the problem is formulated, I'm guessing you are interested in functions which occur in 'daily use' rather than pathological ones. So you could maybe assume the function $f$ is real analytic, write the Taylor Series, and get some equations on the respective coefficients?

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, just some ideas.

The inequality can be rewritten, when $f'(x)\neq0,$ as:

$$f'(x)\left(\frac{f''(x)}{f'(x)}+x-(f(x)+1)f'(x)\right)>0\tag1$$

The interior is the derivative of $$g(x)=\ln|f'(x)|+\frac{x^2-(f(x)+1)^2}2,$$ so $(1)$ means when $f(x)$ is increasing,  then $g(x)$ is increasing and when $f(x)$ is decreasing then $g(x)$ is decreasing.

If $f'(x)=0,$ then we see $f''(x)>0$ so $f(x)$ is a local minimum. Thus, there can be at most one such point.

It seems very difficult to make $g(x)$ increasing if $f(x)$ increases faster than $x.$ That's because you'll need $\ln|f'(x)|$ to compensate for the increases in $f^2(x).$

It seems more likely to find examples with $f'(x)\to 0.$

---

An example which does work is $f(x)=\log(1+x^2)-1.$

Then $f'(x)=\frac{2x}{x^2+1},$ $f''(x)=\frac{2-2x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}$ and you get:

$$f''(x)+xf'(x) -(f(x)+1)(f'(x))^2=\frac{2+2x^4-4x^2\log(1+x^2)}{(1+x^2)^2}$$

Wolfram Alpha gives this is positive. In fact, there are smaller $c$ such that $f(x)=\log(1+x^2)-c$ works.

Specifically, you need:

$$\frac{1+x^4}{2x^2}-\log(1+x^2)>1-c$$

for all $x\neq 0.$ looks like the infimum of possible $c$ is $\approx 0.5941.$

Another example is $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}-c,$ for $c>2.$ I don't have the minimum there.

It seems like a lot of functions $f$ with $f'\to 0$ as $x\to\pm \infty$ with have some value $C$ such that $f(x)-c$ will work for $c$ large enough. You'll definitely need $f$ to have at most one local minimum and no other points where $f'=0.$

I haven't found any strictly increasing $f$ which works yet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is insightful. Your final sentence is indeed the real crux of the problem. I've been thinking of functions of the form $f(x)=e^{x/a}$ but this will never be satisfied as $x\to 0$. And on top of that, ideally $f(x)$ is bounded as $x\to\pm\infty$. I'm beginning to think no such function exists.

Comment: Best not to reference things like "final sentence," since this sort of partial answer will get many edits as I am trying things. $f(x)=e^{x/a}$ is terrible, because the log of its derivative doesn't group as fast as $f(x).$ @neurofunk_quant

Comment: It seems to me you might do better when $f'(x)\to 0$ as $x\to\pm \infty.$ Then $\ln |f'|$ can grow fast why $f$ grows slow. Something like: $f(x)=-\frac1{x^2+1}.$ Not sure yet if that works.

Comment: Why would there be at most one local minimum?

Comment: Because if there is two local minima, there is a local maxima between them, and a local maxima is not possible. @Didier

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Smart move. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks a lot for your work and insights. After revisiting the literature, I noticed that there exists a strict requirement of monotonicity of the function $f(x)$, which means the candidates you have provided are not suitable for my purposes (my apologies for this). I have edited the original question with additional information, along with a couple of candidates that I have come up with. I am curious if you have any further insights given the extra info.